# retain (or strong) attribute does not match the property inherited from nswindowcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, osx-yosemite

When I made my app (non ARC) to 10.10 OS X compatible I am getting this warning for the property

`@property (nonatomic, retain) MasterDocument *document`;

Where `MasterDocument` is of type `NSDocument`.

And I an getting the warning as

> retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'document' does not match the property inherited from NSWindowController.

also getting another warning to the same property like :

> 'atomic' attribute on property 'document' does not match the property inherited from NSWindowController.**

can anyone suggest me the reason to get this warning and how to clear this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created a subclass of `NSWindowController` and you're adding a property that already exists on the parent class.

You're getting this warning because you're changing the definition of the existing property, especially the fact that you're changing the memory management from assign to retain.

The second warning is because you're changing the access from `atomic` to `nonatomic`.

The original property (according to the docs) is:

```
@property(assign) id document
```

You could just omit redeclaring the property and use the existing one, or, at least use the same settings such as:

```
@property (assign) MasterDocument *document;
```

Note of course that you'll be using `assign` and not `retain` or `strong` so make sure you handle the memory correctly.

Comment: The 'document' is my customised object so I need to use it and I am not using the inherited property from NSWindowController. Can I do like this remaining the property other than 'document'. Hope this will clear it. what you say?

Comment: Yes, you could avoid the collision by using a different property name, perhaps something like this: `@property (nonatomic, strong) MasterDocument *masterDocument;`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, your answer resolves and clears the warning.